# Deleting Aliens from a List When Shot - figuring out loops; 'Expression : cannot increment end list iterator'

Tags: c++, list, visual-c++

I asked a question about this project [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662191/list-vs-vector-with-abstract-classes) (this isn't the same problem), but I'm working on a imitation of Space Invaders for an assignment. I have almost everything working, but I'm having problems with the bullet-alien interaction. I'm new to lists, so I apologize if it's an obvious problem. :)

I have a function for making the aliens disappear when they intersect with the bullets, but when the bullet kills two of them, or if the bullet flies past them and disappears, the program gets stuck in an infinite loop (outer loop).

This is the function involved :

(if you need to see anything from the other classes, I can add those too)

```
void alienGroupMgr::disappear(shotMgr m)
{
    // shotMgr is just a class that manages the bullet data (vector of ptrs to bullets)  
    // getSprite returns data about individual sprites               

    for (list<alien*>::iterator iter = theGang.begin();iter != theGang.end();) // each alien
    {
        alien* ptrShot = *iter;
        FloatRect alienBound = ptrShot->getSprite().getGlobalBounds();

        // theGang is a list of ptrs to aliens from the alien group mgr class
        // alien is a class for each alien

        for (int i = 0; i < m.getAmountFilled(); i++) // each bullet
        {   // getlist returns an index from the vector of bullet ptrs
            FloatRect bulletBound = m.getList(i)->getSprite().getGlobalBounds();

            if (alienBound.intersects(bulletBound))
            {
                iter = theGang.erase(iter);
            }
            else
            {
                iter++;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I tested a version of the function where I limited the outer loop to 9 times through using a counter. It works half of the time and the other half, it gives an error that says 'Expression : cannot increment end list iterator'.

I would really appreciate some advice! Thanks.

Comment: I think you should test for the end in the second loop, like `iter != theGang.end()` in the condition. The `iter` seems to go beyond the end since you don't check it in the second loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems strange that you have that iter++ line inside the inner loop.

For example, think about the case when no bullet intersects with any alien. Then I guess you want the code to go through all the combinations, but that will not happen because you have the iter++ line happening each time there was no intersection.

I would suggest that instead of removing from theGang inside the inner loop, use a bool variable that is false before the inner loop and that you set to true if you find an intersection with any bullet. Then, after the inner loop, you check the bool variable to see if you should remove the alien. Then it becomes easier to see what the code is doing: first check if the alien is hit by any bullet, then remove the alien if it was hit.